# how to convert canvas tag in html to a word file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I don't know how to convert a canvas tag to a word file.

I tried the jQuery Word Export plugin using [this tutorial](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin.html) but I got this error :

```
TypeError: $(...).wordExport is not a function
```

Here is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a.word-export").click(function(event) {
        $("#page-content").wordExport();
    });
});
```

Comment: We will need more code to see where the problem is located.

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to show us the error, since you're asking for help related to that error?

Comment: As the docs on the page you linked to say, did you "Make sure to include the word export plugin after jQuery library and filesaver.js."?

Comment: What if you would make picture of canvas and then proccess it as picture?
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

Comment: @AlonEitan i said i got  TypeError: $(...).wordExport is not a function .

Comment: @mansim how to create a word file by this image?

Comment: @j08691yes i included word export plugin

Comment: @Jordumus i used the link that post.but i got this erro " TypeError: $(...).wordExport is not a function"

Comment: You could first save whole webpage source into a different html file locally. Then make image from canvas and save it locally. Then replace canvas inside saved source code with this image. Then use your software to convert this html file into word document.

Comment: @mansim this link dont work properly for me.when i want to save a div tag i got TypeError: $(...).wordExport is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably something wrong with your code, or something not loaded. Probably WordExport doesn't exist in your source or loaded under your script.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js'></script>
// And here link to file of jquery.wordexport.js source
```

Check this fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/mansim/at148xnm/` where it works and see what did you do wrong

Comment: sorry,i want to just  run this  "$("#page-content").wordExport();" part of code,i added the wordexport to my source and load it under two .js file..but i got this error "TypeError: $(...).wordExport is not a function"

Comment: Its obviously not correctly loaded wordexport library. as you see in my example it works naturally. If you want better help you should post your whole code, only then is possible to find your mistake.

Comment: according to whats you say i create a div tag and put an image in it.and when call word.export got an error

var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
  iDiv.id = 'block';
  iDiv.className = 'block';
  var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("jade-schematic-diagram");
  var image = new Image();
  image.id = "pic"
  image.src = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
  iDiv.appendChild(image);
  $(".block").wordExport();

Comment: TypeError: $(...).wordExport is not a function